# The code snipet from a real Web application - explation needed

Tags: css, web-applications, client-side, web

Engaging in reverse engineering I found today the following snipet:

```
<script id="idea" type="text/x-jqote-template">
    <![CDATA[
    <li data-idea_id="<*= this.id *>" class="voted">
      <div class="vote_panel">
        <div class="vote_count"><*= this.votes_count *></div>
        <span class="vote_action vote">You've already voted</span>
      </div>  
      <div class="idea_details">
        <h4 class="title"><*= this.title *> <a href='#' class='toggle_description more details'>Details</a></h4>
        <div class="description_metadata_pane" style="display: none;">
          <p class="description"><*= this.description *></p>
          <p class="metadata">- <*= this.name *> on <*= this.created_at *></p>
      </div>
    </li>
    ]]>
</script>
```

Could someone explain how does this work, and where data comes from (server- or client-side)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a client-side template engine (I know, insane) called [jQote2](http://aefxx.com/jquery-plugins/jqote2/).

It loads the contents of the `<script>` tag and uses jQuery to render it clientside.